# Two selects with table columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, multiple-columns

I have a table with multiple columns. I have two select boxes:

- one to change the background color of the highlighted column
- one to select which column to highlight

This assumes that I click the `#colorselect` select box first. Do I need to create another function with the `#columnselect` select box first, then `#colorselect` function built inside?

Here's what I have so far:

```js
$(function(){
    $("#colorselect").change(function() {
        $("#colorselect option:selected").each(function() {
            if($(this).attr("value")=="red") {
                clr="red"
            }

            if($(this).attr("value")=="green") {
                clr="green"
            }

            if($(this).attr("value")=="") {
                clr="yellow"
            }
        };

        $("#columnselect").change(function() {
            $("#columnselect option:selected").each(function() {
                if($(this).attr("value")=="column1") {
                    columnhighlightsel="Column1"
                }

                if($(this).attr("value")=="column2") {
                    columnhighlightsel="Column2"
                }

                if($(this).attr("value")=="") {
                    columnhighlightsel="Column2"
                }
            }

            for (var i = 0; i<= $("#table th").length; i++) {
                if($.trim($("#dailytable th:nth-child("+i+")").text()) === columnhighlightsel) {
                    varcolumnhighlight=i
                }
            };

            $("#table tbody tr td:nth-child("+columnhighlight+")").each(function() {
                $(this).css('background-color', clr);
            };
```

Comment: Can you please post your HTML? Presumably, you'd need the column select first before the column color change unless you have a "default" column...

Comment: DIDN'T GET YOUR PROBLEM,But you should close the jquery change function

like this }); and not like this };

Comment: Check the updated question, you had serious missing closing `})` issues.

Comment: Oops! Thanks silentw.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just write a single function that handles a change in either column. Check if either is blank before executing the code. Then the order doesn't matter.

Then just make the values in your color select the colors you want, and the column the number of the column:

```
$('#colorselect, #columnselect').change(function() {
  var $color = $('#colorselect').val(),
      $column = $('#columnselect').val();
  if ($color && $column) {
    $("#table tbody tr td:nth-child("+$column+")").each(function(){
      $(this).css('background-color', $color);
    };
  }
});
```

Depending on your values, you may have to adjust the if condition to be more specific.

Comment: Thanks! That's very helpful. I knew I was making this more complicated than it is.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#colorselect").change(function(){
           clr = $("#colorselect option:selected").attr("value");
        clr = clr == '' ? 'yellow' : clr;
        color();
    }

   $("#columnselect").change(function(){

         columnhighlightsel= $(this);
        color();
    }

function color(){
   if(!columnhighlightsel || !clr){
      return;
   }
   columnhighlightsel.css('background-color', clr);
}
```

You now have to get the columnhighlightsel and clr- variables into the color-function context.